# pack array for variadic

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

I know that it's relatively easy to go from Args... args to an array like:

```
template<typename...Args> 
void f(Args...args){
    double list[] = {args...};
}
```

But, is there a way to go back to an Args, like:

```
template<typename...Args> 
void f(Args...args){
    double list[] = {args...};
    //manipulate list[]
    //convert list to new_args...
    //use it in a function
    any_other_f(new_args...);
}
```

Comment: What a mess, can you please clean this up and ask a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never say never. Since it appears that you know the size of the `list` (=`sizeof...(args)`), you can try your luck with a c++14 library feature and create an `index_sequence` that you then use for indexing the list during unpacking. Look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence. The examples at the bottom show how to do it.

My first attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template<typename... Args>
void any_other_f(Args... args)
{
    double list[] = {args...};
    for (auto&& x : list)
        cout << x << ", ";
    cout << "\n";
}

template<typename T, size_t... I>
void wrapper_function(T&& t, index_sequence<I...>)
{
    any_other_f(t[I]...);   
}

template<typename...Args> 
void f(Args...args)
{
    constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(args);
    double list[] = {args...};
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        list[i] *= -1;
    wrapper_function(list, make_index_sequence<size>());
}

int main() 
{
    f(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
}
```

and it works: http://ideone.com/OmfOps.

The only requirement is you need to know the size of the thing you would like to unpack at compile time. Or atleast you need to make a guess that then crashes at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in the way you'd like to do. The contents of an array is a dynamic thing, the target of a function call (even if it's variadic) is decided compile time. Why would you like to do such a thing? Probably there's a better way.

Comment: I would like to differentiate a generic function f(x, args...), so I would need to call something like f(x, d_args...).